# Получить данные в одном запросе MySql?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с данными о товарах product = (title, price).

Можно ли в одном запросе сделать следующую задачу:
- Получить 2 товара с ценой ниже чем у текущей цены,
- Получить 2 товара с ценой выше чем у текущей цены.

Цену передаем в запрос.

Как можно выкрутиться?

Comment: Предположу что два `SELECT` с лимитом 2 объединив через `UNION` ... Вам по два товара, даже если их больше?

Comment: джойним таблицу саму к себе 4 раза? ) @АлексейШиманский, а лимит разве не на всю выборку применится? Т.е. вы выберете две случайные записи, а не две с той и другой стороны

Comment: ого, это как джойнить таблицу саму к себе?)))) Если логика выборки неправильная, то я не против сделать и два запроса. Просто скажите что так нельзя.

Comment: @ВОРОН ....ну.........как сказать.....http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/UNION.html

Comment: @ВОРОН то, что случайные да. но автор ничего не упомянул про то, что конкретно надо. поэтому я не пишу это как ответ, а лишь так, предположил

Comment: @duddeniska Так как вам надо выбрать по 2 записи? любые две или строго какие либо?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я думал так нельзя )) "случайные" - это если за скобки вынести, а в вашем случае это очень даже ответ.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Допусти товар с ценой 1000 р. Мне нужно найти рядом стоящие товары по цене. Допусти 2 товара ниже по 900 и 800 рублей. И так же выше стоящие по цене 2 товара. 1100 и 1200рублей

Comment: то есть ближайшие по цене сверху и снизу ?

Comment: @splash58 да все верно

Comment: Не мучайте БД, сделайте 2 запроса. При нагрузках по отдельности работать быстрее будут. И к тому же обрабатывать вы же будете тоже отдельно?

Comment: а зачем обрабатывать отдельно - добавить в юнион price=PRICE (если нужно) и в самом конце order by price, сразу получится правильный порядок для вывода

Comment: @splash58 а вы можете это как один из ответов написать? Чтобы было понятно, что имеете в виду. А может и ваш перевыберут)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тока добрался до компа. А оно надо? Аскер не просил :)

Comment: @splash58 ну дело ваше. Мне лично интересно о чем речь) Можете комментом написать. Чисто для меня))

Comment: вот, накидал - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a32e5/3

Comment: @splash58 хм, так это ж то, что я написал. Да даже еще больше)) я думал что другое будет)) Спасибо.)

Comment: собственно, я это и писал в коменте:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь получится так:

```
(SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `price` > YOUR_PRICE  ORDER BY `price` ASC LIMIT 2)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `price` < YOUR_PRICE ORDER BY `price` DESC LIMIT 2)
```

где `YOUR_PRICE` - ваша сравниваемая цена.

`ORDER BY price DESC` - нужен чтоб взять именно ближайшие цены к сравниваемой, иначе возьмутся нижние самые

Comment: Спасибо, а как еще воткнуть что бы выбирал именно в этой категории. Делаю вот так не работает (SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `price` > YOUR_PRICE  and and id_category=3 and id_subcategory = 2 ORDER BY `price` ASC LIMIT 2)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `price` < YOUR_PRICE and id_category=3 and id_subcategory = 2ORDER BY `price` DESC LIMIT 2)

Comment: @duddeniska ошибку выдает или ничего не выдает? а то у вас два раза подряд `and` написан и `ORDER BY` слитно.. так то должно работать при любых доп условиях

Comment: @duddeniska обратите внимание на то что имеется `ORDER BY` в запросах. он не просто так...... а то смотрю сюда http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477333/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-union-mysql  и вас этого нет.....

Comment: да я там тестировал запрос, а так все верно, ваш запрос работает. уже реализовал. Я делал это что бы выводить похожие товары данного товара